# Can I get a hint on how to integrate $1+ \sin^2 x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, trigonometry

I'm working on a line integral problem and have simplified to the integrand

$$(1+ \sin^2 \theta)d\theta$$

What can I do from here?

Thanks,

Comment: HINT: $$sin^2(\theta) = \frac{1-cos(2\theta)}{2}$$

Comment: Do you know the way of expressing $\sin ^2 x$ in terms of $\cos 2x$

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks - I should have known to go for a power-reducing strategy.  I am rusty / weak in some high-school math that I no longer use often.  Thanks @AritraDas.

Comment: Thanks so much for the hint @Shailesh :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use integration by parts:
$ \int \sin^2(x) dx = \int \sin(x) \sin(x) dx $

Now remember that $ \int a\cdot b' = a\cdot b  - \int a' \cdot b $ and $\sin^2 + \cos^2 = 1$

Comment: Thanks so much @Christian :-)

Comment: @Christian, should we use $\int a.b'[dx]$ instead of $\int a.b'$? Is $dx$ needed?

Comment: The second line is just a compact form, as you can see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts

Answer (score 2):

Remember the trigonometric identity: $$2\sin^2(x)-1= -\cos(2x)$$

Answer (score 2):

Notice, $$\int(1+\sin^2 x)dx=\int\left(1+\frac{1-\cos 2x}{2}\right)dx=\int\left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\cos 2x}{2}\right)dx$$$$=\frac{3}{2}\int\ dx+\frac{1}{4}\int\cos 2x\ d(2x)$$

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an easy problem, it is hard once you throw other trigs in their. I suggest the best thing you can do is read chapter 7.2 page 497 in calculus 7ed, it will explain it very well.

$$\int(1+\sin^2x)\ \mathrm dx$$

First, substitute in the identity
$$\sin^2x = \frac12(1-\cos2x)$$

You will have
$$\int\left(1+\frac12\right)(1-\cos2x)\ \mathrm dx$$

You need to remember that if you have $$\int(x+4)\ \mathrm dx=\int x\ \mathrm dx+\int4\ \mathrm dx$$

so you will have
$$\int1\ \mathrm dx+\frac12\int(1-\cos2x)\ \mathrm dx$$

You can do the same thing here
$$\int1\ \mathrm dx+\frac12\int(1-\cos2x)\ \mathrm dx
= \int1\ \mathrm dx+\frac12\left[\int1-\int\cos2x\right]\ \mathrm dx$$

Now you have
$$\int1\ \mathrm dx+\frac12\left[\int1-\int\cos2x\right]\ \mathrm dx$$
Working this out is easy, I think you should know what to do after.

The answer should be
$$x+\frac12\left(x-\frac{\sin2x}2\right)$$
and if you put it all together you'll have
$$\frac{3x}2 - \frac{\sin2x}4$$
Don't go further

I didn't show you how get solve $\int$ but I'll show you how to solve its derivative

Solve for 
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\frac{3x}2 - \frac{\sin2x}4\right)$$
First factor out the $\frac12$
You'll have 
$$\frac12\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(3x-\frac{\sin2x}2\right)$$
Compute the derivative you'll get 
$$\begin{align}
\frac12(3-\cos2x)
&= \frac12(2+1-\cos2x)\\
&= \frac22 + \frac{1-\cos2x}2 &\text{by grouping}\\
&= 1 + \sin^2x
\end{align}$$

Comment: See [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to format Maths using Mathjax.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
 $$(\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta))'=\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta)=1-2\sin^2(\theta).$$

Then use

$$1+\sin^2(\theta)=\frac{3-(1-2\sin^2(\theta))}{2}=\left(\frac{3\theta-\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}2\right)'.$$

Comment: Very cool approach @YvesDaoust :-)